# IE8 event coordinates

Tags: javascript, events, internet-explorer-8, coordinates, dom-events

I can't seem to find a way to get coordinates of event in IE8, it just triggers errors like... "pageX undefined", "clientX undefined" etc. While it works fine in other browsers.

This is what I was trying to do:

```
document.onmousemove=setcoord;

function setcoord(e){
    var xxcoord = e.pageX||(e.clientX+document.body.scrollLeft);
    var yycoord = e.pageY||(e.clientY+document.body.scrollTop);
}
```

Is there any workaround to get that mouse position?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following seems to work. I'm not sure its is the proper way to do this:

```
var x=event.clientX;
var y=event.clientY;
```

Comment: This is correct. Explanation: Prior IE 9, Microsoft did not implement the W3 DOM event model. Instead, they used a proprietary event model: Event listeners do not receive any arguments; any event-related property is defined on the global `event` object. A generic solution is to add `e = e || window.event;` at the top of the event listener.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now, there is still a problem with that though which is that e.clientX does not account for scrolling and document.body.scrollLeft doesn't seem to work in IE either... I mean if I scroll the window it gets me not the absolute coords but related to the viewport.

Comment: aight, documentElement seems to work. :) EDIT: **BUT** it doesn't work in chrome now... oh noes..

Comment: True. I found this previous question that seems to deal with the scroll issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307307/click-mouse-position-with-scroll-in-javascript