# pageX pageY not working in IE8 if i add <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

Hey guys i have the following script which gives me cursor position when i move the mouse .
this script works fine in chrome,FF and even in IE 8(without **!doctype html**)

if add   **!DOCTYPE html**  to the html page.
it gives me object doesnt support this property error. and the below given line is causing the problem

**document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);**

How can i fix this problem with **!DOCTYPE html** included in IE 8.

```
window.onload = init;
    function init() {
   if (window.Event) {
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
   }
  document.onmousemove = getCursorXY;
    }

  function getCursorXY(e) {
      document.getElementById('cursorX').value = (window.Event) ? e.pageX :   
         event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ?    
       document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
     document.getElementById('cursorY').value = (window.Event) ? e.pageY : event.clientY  
   + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop :    
    document.body.scrollTop);
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK, for IE below 9 you should use `clientX`/`clientY`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042275/javascript-ie8-event-coordinates

Comment: This link helped me
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307307/click-mouse-position-with-scroll-in-javascript>

thanks a lot guys!!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are receiving the error because `<!DOCTYPE html>` is the declaration for HTML5 and IE 8 won't be able to process HTML5.

Have you considered to switch to jQuery? It will have all the functions needed to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, not supported for IE9-.
You can check these kinds of compatibility issues from this link. http://quirksmode.org/compatibility.html

Answer (score -1):

Use the IE DOM event equivalent to the W3C DOM event:

```
W3C DOM                   IE DOM
clientX                   (pageX - pageXOffset)
clientY                   (pageY - pageYOffset)
offsetX                   pageXOffset
offsetY                   pageYOffset
```

And switch via lazy evaluation with W3C as the default API:

```
 clientX || (pageX - pageXOffset);
```

**References**

- [IE Event Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535863)