# Mouse Event Properties are Undefined on IE 11

Tags: javascript, debugging, window, internet-explorer-11, eventhandler

The following code I'm using to Identify the browser window close event and works as intended on other browsers but not on IE11. As this line of code gives me `undefined` only on IE11 `alert(event.clientY+":"+event.clientX);`.Can anyone please suggest a solution to this problem.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) 
{
event= window.event|| event;
alert(event);
alert(event.clientY+":"+event.clientX);

    if(event.clientX <0 || event.clientY < 0)
    {   
        // ajax call to server to nullify the session.
        window.close();
    }
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pageX pageY not working in IE8 if i add <!DOCTYPE html>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272820/pagex-pagey-not-working-in-ie8-if-i-add-doctype-html)

Comment: No, my question is for IE 11 and not for IE8

Comment: So... What should happen if my cursor is in the middle of the screen and I hit Alt+F4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MDN [beforeunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) you may see what properties are supported from event object.

The clientX and clientY of the event object are not supported so they are undefined.

This happens also in Chrome and FF because the onbeforeunload event does not contain such information (positional X and Y)

I tested your code in IE11, Chrome 48, FF 44.

A possible workaround coud be:

```js
var clientX = 0;
var clientY = 0;
var scheduled = false;

window.onmousemove = function (event) {
  if (!scheduled) {
    scheduled = true;
    setTimeout(function () {
      event = event || window.event;
      clientX = event.clientX;
      clientY = event.clientY;
      scheduled = false;
    }, 1000);
  }
}

window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
  alert(clientY+":"+clientX);
  if (clientX < 0 || clientY < 0) {
    // ajax call to server to nullify the session.
    window.close();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The event object is defined twice:

```
event = window.event || event;
```

but the reference is not used here:

```
if(window.event.clientX < 0 || window.event.clientY < 0)
```

so IE fails because the code should be:

```
if(event.clientX < 0 || event.clientY < 0)
```

Comment: @psyLogic gaemaf answered the beforeUnload part of the question.