# position to mouse co ordinates after scrolling body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouse-coordinates

If i am positioning a child div in accordance with the `mouse co-ordinates` inside a parent div, without scrolling the body, the child is being positioned properly. Now if a scroll the body such that the parent div is just visible, and now click on the parent, to position the child, the child is not being positioned. please suggest a way such that i will be able to position the child even after scrolling the body. Please find the same case in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/8N63U/).Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307307/click-mouse-position-with-scroll-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. My problem got solved with `e.pageY` See the following working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/8N63U/2/)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

`e.clientY` = position Y of cursor on window

`$('.a').offset().top` = the position in document body of the top of `.a` area (if you need to change `margin-top` of `.a`, you better subtract this value).

`$(window).scrollTop()` = the distance you scrolled

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.a').on('click',function(e){
        var positionClick =  e.clientY - $('.a').offset().top + $(window).scrollTop();
        $('.b').css('top',positionClick);
    });
});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/8N63U/1/

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the other answer, you can add the scroll offset when defining the top:

```
$('.b').css('top',e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop);
```

Your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s75m4/) updated.